# Unable to start CopyQ - despite process working

Tags: copy

One of my favorite plugin does not work, I have checked in console and it seems working fine:

```
twaszczyk@ktwtomwasnb:~$ copyq --version
CopyQ Clipboard Manager v3.10.0
Qt: 5.12.5
Compiler: GCC
Arch: x86_64-little_endian-lp64
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
twaszczyk@ktwtomwasnb:~$ copyq
Warning: CopyQ server is already running.

twaszczyk@ktwtomwasnb:~$ copyq show
ERROR: Cannot connect to server! Start CopyQ server first.
```

Any idea? I use it many times per day. But when I copy something I got a window:

[image]

Seems like some upgrade which causes that there is no icon in a tray.

**UPDATE:**

```
twaszczyk@ktwtomwasnb:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

In that way I was trying to install but does not work:

```
twaszczyk@ktwtomwasnb:~$ sudo flatpak install com.github.hluk.copyq
[sudo] password for twaszczyk: 
Looking for matches…
error: No remote refs found similar to ‘com.github.hluk.copyq’
twaszczyk@ktwtomwasnb:~$ flatpak install flathub com.github.hluk.copyq
Looking for matches…
error: No remote refs found similar to ‘flathub’
```

Do I really need to install all those stuff to run those `simple` application????

[image]

Comment: From your question, I cannot make up what desktop environment you are using. It can also be relevant to mention the specific Ubuntu version (`lsb_release -a`).

Comment: @vanadium updated ;-)

Comment: Oops, I see that that info actually was also in the output of CopyQ, so likely you are using the Gnome Shell desktop indeed. I see your comment in flathub ;) , but the version you give suggests you currently use a regular apt install. Try removing that (`sudo remove copyq`) and installing the flatpak version (`flatpak install com.github.hluk.copyq`).

Comment: So Ubuntu next time switches from `apt` to `snap` to `flatpak`??

Comment: Nope, Ubuntu stays with snap. I have flatpak enabled, and I see your comment in gnome-software. Anyway, the developper site indicates the existence of a PPA, so that is yet another way of installing to work around the malfunctioning of your current install.

Comment: So how to install now CopyQ - on the second machine CopyQ stops to work ;-((((

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question is here (https://github.com/hluk/CopyQ/issues/1526):

```
sh -c "sleep 10; copyq"
```

Just add hacky delay in order to run the app. For me it works.